# ajax not working in chrome

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

So I have this script which posts some text using ajax:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['q'])) {
    echo 'q is '.$_POST['q'];
} else {
?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script>
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("POST","aj.php",true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept","text/html");
                xmlhttp.send("q=some text");
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                  if(xmlhttp.readyState===4&&xmlhttp.status===200)
                    if (r=xmlhttp.response||xmlhttp.responseText) 
                        document.write(r);
                    else 
                        alert("no response")
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            body
        </body>
    </html>
<?php } ?>
```

The output is suppose to be 'q is some text' but in Google Chrome (Windows) it runs repeatedly and all you see is the word 'body' repeating across the page.
Whats going wrong?

Comment: `if (r=xmlhttp.response||xmlhttp.responseText) document.write(r); else alert("no response")` If it does not define `r` what do you expect to write in your web page? Give thanks if it already writes `body` in your document.

Comment: and you're not using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) because? :)

Comment: Your code work in chrome, without problems, maybe you have wrong the page name

Comment: Why you torture yourself by not using JQUERY?

Comment: This is a suggestion to anyone that does not use jQuery. If you don't want to use plugins to do ajax call, atleast use a custom function to do an ajax call with parameters needed or something like jQuery ajax call. Do not write that amazing code every time you want to do an ajax call. It's ugly and unreadable.

Comment: No, you get the toolkit for free so you don't need to melt, assemble and maintain your own screwdriver

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is the way

```
$.post('ajax.php','q=some text',function(data){
    $(document.body).html(data);
 });
```